# Node: Uncaught TypeError: moduleClass is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, image, quill

I want to import handler in quill.
But i am still getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: moduleClass is not a constructor`

This is how function with quill works

```
import Quill from 'quill';

// IMAGE HANDLER
    const imageHandler = () => {
      const input = document.createElement('input');

      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
      input.click();

      input.onchange = async () => {
        const file = input.files[0];
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('image', file);

        // Save current cursor state
        const range = this.quill.getSelection(true);

        // Insert temporary loading placeholder image
        this.quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', `${ window.location.origin }/images/loaders/placeholder.gif`);

        // Move cursor to right side of image (easier to continue typing)
        this.quill.setSelection(range.index + 1);

        const res = await apiPostNewsImage(formData); // API post, returns image location as string e.g. 'http://www.example.com/images/foo.png'

        // Remove placeholder image
        this.quill.deleteText(range.index, 1);

        // Insert uploaded image
        this.quill.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', res.body.image);
      }
    }

// Initialize quill
    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
      theme: 'snow',
      modules: {
        toolbar: '#toolbar',
        handlers: {
          image: imageHandler,
        }
      }
    });
```

When i open where is error it gaves mi this part of code from quill.js

```
{
    key: 'addModule',
    value: function addModule(name) {
      var moduleClass = this.quill.constructor.import('modules/' + name);
      this.modules[name] = new moduleClass(this.quill, this.options.modules[name] || {});
      return this.modules[name];
    }
```

I am not sure if done someting wrong or if is problem on quill side.

Answer (score 2):

I initially also got this error, but I solved it by changing the modules structure in the following way:

```
modules: {
   toolbar: {
      container: '#toolbar',
      handlers: {
         image: imageHandler
      }
   }
}
```

Note that the handlers are now defined inside toolbar instead of next to it (see https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/ for documentation).

Answer (score 0):

When i use quill-mention and try to extracting ReactQuill and turning it into a component than face the same problem.

I solve this by use `Mention.default` than `Mention` when we register modules/mention

```
Quill.register(
  {
    'modules/emoji': quillEmoji,
    'modules/mention': Mention.default
  },
  true
);
```